# string literal too long clob

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a procedure that insert data to a table.
Example procedure:

```
procedure pSave(sRefer in varchar2,
                cMsgQueue in clob) is
                
begin
  insert into table1 (REFER, MSG)
               values(sRefer, cMsgQueue);
end;
```

The size of the cMsgQueue clob is `204017` (characters).

When starting the procedure, I get the error string literal too long.

How can you write a large clob into a table with one referee.

If you transfer small pieces, the procedure works without error.

Comment: What is datatype of MSG?

Comment: @Aman Singh Rajpoot, clob

Comment: How do you call this procedure? If from console, then it will treat your text as `varchar2` first

Comment: @astentx, via test procedure

Comment: You may use the DBMS_LOB package to load CLOB in chunks.

Comment: OK, so how does your test procedure define and pass the value? The issue isn't with the procedure you showed, it's with how you are calling it - presumably by trying to pass the entire value as a string literal. You can build up the value from shorter string literals, but that only maybe makes sense for a test; for real use you need to think about where the values will come from and how they will be passed in to the procedure too.

Comment: If you will call that procedure from outside the DB, you need to bind a clob variable to character stream or something similar depending on the language. Then write the data to it and do actual call. If you call this procedure from somewhere inside the database, you need to wrap the data with `to_clob` and pass it to the procedure. Anyway, the error indicates you have `varchar2` somewhere inbetween, so you need to check all your declarations and string literals. Now your question lacks details about actual procedure call.

Comment: @Alex Poole, You are right, I tested in oracle in a test script